# Why is my object deallocated in swift?

Tags: macos, swift, object, memory-management

I have a NSTextField with a binding value - bind to delegate "self.myObject.Title"
Running this code

```
@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    var myObject = OwnObject()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        myObject = OwnObject()
        print(myObject.Title)
    }

}

class OwnObject: NSObject {

    var Title : String! = ""

    override init() {

        super.init()
        self.Title = "This is a title"

    }
}
```

will fill the correct title to the TextField but myObject will be deallocated automatically and I am getting this error

```
2015-06-16 15:43:55.587 testapp109[7896:463502] An instance 0x60000004d4d0 of class testapp109.OwnObject was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x6080000538c0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x6080000c3aa0: Observer: 0x6080000c3a30, Key path: Title, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x608000053890>
)
```

Why is the object deallocated and how can i prevent this?
Thanks

Comment: Which one? Where are observers added? You create 2 instances of `OwnObject` so you need to give more info (and explain why you're creating 2 and if you know you're doing it)

Comment: The observers are added in InterfaceBuilder. Hey you're right. Didn't see that I created 2 Objects. As the 2nd object will overwrite the 1st the error message makes sense

Comment: Like @Wain said, you are creating two object instances (one for initializing the variable and another one inside the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`), maybe the error comes from deallocating the first one.